# Awt Robot key press delay

Tags: java, awtrobot, jintellitype

I work on a small tool for a game something like hotkey which handle a combination of user key press event and simulate with Awt Robot a couple of key press. The problem is that called method ghostWalk() work as expected only first time when registered combination is pressed, second time when I press the same combination and the same method are called only the last key is simulated which is after "robot.delay". pls read more from code comment.

```
import com.melloware.jintellitype.HotkeyListener;
import com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitype;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class L {
int i = 160;

public static void main(String args[]){
    L l = new L();
    l.k();
}
public void k(){
    // Register keys combination
    JIntellitype.getInstance();
    JIntellitype.getInstance().registerHotKey(1, JIntellitype.MOD_ALT, (int)'D');
    JIntellitype.getInstance().registerHotKey(2, JIntellitype.MOD_ALT, (int)'J');
    JIntellitype.getInstance().registerHotKey(3, JIntellitype.MOD_ALT, (int)'K');
    JIntellitype.getInstance().addHotKeyListener(new HotkeyListener() {
        public void onHotKey(int aIdentifier) {
            // First indentifier Alt + D
            if (aIdentifier == 1) {
                System.out.println("Alt+D hotkey pressed");
                // Start new thread
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        L gh = new L();
                        gh.ghostWalk();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
            // Second indetifier
            else if(aIdentifier == 2){
                i += 10;
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            // Third
            else if(aIdentifier == 3){
                i -= 10;
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    });
}
// Method called to simulate key press
/* So, first time when i press Alt + D in game after program runs
all work good, the keys are simulated  as expected but if I press again and again
the combination only key "d" are simulated which is after "delay(i), i = 160"
If program is restarted all again is the same, only first time when i press registered
combinations the program work as expected.
Second and others times program work only if there is delay "robot = new Robot();
                                                             robot.delay(100);"
 on 100 delay program work well on 40ms need to press very fast the combination
 so the program work as expected. How to fix it ? to simulate key press without
 delay like first time when program is run.
 P.s no matter in which window(game, notepad) you press combination to simulate key press
 still work good only first time.
Example of output when i press two times combinations in game
first time: qqwewwd
second time: d
 */
public void ghostWalk(){
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        //robot.delay(100);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.delay(i);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

**Edit:** I can't understand what changes are made after first calling ghostWalk method that I should to use delay so my program work as expected.

**Edit2:** In my case code start to work when `setAutoWaitForIdle` was set to true and `delay` = 5 (delay before start to simulate keypress) also if between 
keypress is a delay like in my case delay(i), i = 160 then start delay should be 60~. (if start delay is 40~ then not always work good, need very fast to press registered keys combination idk why, also if start delay is less than 40-60 in my case is simulated only last keypress "D" which is after delay(i).)

If to delete `robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true)` and `robot.delay(60)` on first registered hotkey event the tool will work as expected, on second, third etc times - not. After first JIntellitype event work only this code.

```
public void ghostWalk(){
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
        robot.delay(60);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);;
        robot.delay(i);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying if you increase the delay, your program works as expected, but you don't want a delay?

Comment: Yep.. in steam for example or in another software which not change focus when you press alt this work as expected then I press Alt D no delay, nothing wrong all work good. First I thought maybe this is some game limits but first time work perfectly + I have a tool which is not written by me and it work with game like as i want to do in my tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider setting an auto-delay using [setAutoDelay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#setAutoDelay%28int%29).

It's quite possible your OS has problems handling input events if they're posted without delay. Try with 50 ms or 25ms delay, see what happens.

Another thing you can try is add [`waitForIdle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#waitForIdle%28%29) before each key press.

---

**EDIT:** For sports I tried the [JIntelliType library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jintellitype/downloads) out, and the following snippet works relatively well. I tested pressing the hotkey out in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (`ctrl-Q`) and it consistently prints out `tt rocks`. However I had to release the hotkey fast, otherwise Notepad++ started interpreting the hotkey as something else (`ctrl-Q` is already a shortcut for something else in Notepad++).

Using a robot is not exact science. I had to delay the robot for 150 ms and then `waitForIdle` before letting the robot press keys. Otherwise things got screwed up. Setting auto delay was not necessary.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import com.melloware.jintellitype.HotkeyListener;
import com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitype;

public class TestKeys {
    private HotkeyListener listener = new HotkeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHotKey(final int hotKeyId) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JIntellitype.getInstance().removeHotKeyListener(listener);
                    handleHotKey(hotKeyId);
                    JIntellitype.getInstance().addHotKeyListener(listener);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    };

    public void registerHotKeys() {
        JIntellitype instance = JIntellitype.getInstance();
        instance.registerHotKey(1, JIntellitype.MOD_CONTROL, 'Q');
        instance.registerHotKey(2, JIntellitype.MOD_CONTROL, 'J');
        instance.addHotKeyListener(listener);
        System.out.println("Hotkeys registered");
    }

    private static void handleHotKey(int hotKeyId) {
        switch(hotKeyId) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Pressing some keys now!");
                pressSomeKeys();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Bailing out, cya!");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void pressSomeKeys() {
        Robot r;
        try {
            r = new Robot();
        } 
        catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("Creating robot failed");
            System.exit(2);
            return;
        }
        r.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
        r.delay(150);
        r.waitForIdle();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_K); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_K);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    }

    public static synchronized void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("TestKeys started");
        TestKeys k = new TestKeys();
        k.registerHotKeys();
        try { 
            TestKeys.class.wait();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, idk why when robot.setAutoDelay(50); first q is not writing, all other work but very slow.

Comment: @N.A Well 50ms was just an example; 25ms could work too. I've updated my answer with another suggestion (`waitForIdle`). If that doesn't work, perhaps you could add a *fake* key press if it's always the first key press that gets ignored.

Comment: TT. Thanks for help. Please read main post one more time I edited him and if you have some ideas about this pls tell me if not just tell me something like " no, thx" so I can accept your answer, I just don't know if you or me will can still to comment in this thread if I will accept your answer now.

Comment: @N.A I've updated my answer with a snippet that works relatively well on my system.

Comment: Your code work very well with start delay 150 or 100 even 60 if you press very fast but there is no difference between your and my code, both work with start delay more than 60. You can reproduce my problem if you reduce in your code the delay to 5 or 10 and try it in steam store search textbox, in steam the focus from textbox is not moving out when you press Alt or Ctrl. You probably will see on first registered hotkey event that code work very well and "tt rocks" is writing as expected but on second event only space is write, no matter how much times you try.

Comment: @N.A I think this is due to an OS restriction involving interactions between hotkey listeners and the robot you start. I am no expert so I'm afraid I cannot help you any further. To me the 150ms delay is OK, seems fast enough. With that delay the characters were typed out without problem. Is it a problem to have that delay for your situation?

Comment: @N.A It's quite possible that when the hotkey is pressed, then your listener is started when your hotkey is still being pressed. You can't have characters typed out when your hotkey is still being pressed. That's what the delay is for. I have no idea how to solve this without adding the delay.